# Is it best practice to use a tag inside a question?

Tags: discussion, tags

In a question body such as this one, it is possible to insert tags. This is an example: [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag) or [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion).

The notation is:

```
[tag:tag_name]
```

Is that good practice? Or plain annoying? I personally find it quite useful as it links to SO's official definition for that word rather than referring to a third party site.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1ep6C.png Think--if it were bad, why would it exist? SE could turn it off at any time they wanted.

Comment: It's great on meta. It's pretty rare to see it on main sites, but I suppose it has some marginal value; it's almost never misused.

Answer (score 9):

If you're talking about the tag, then you should be using the tag notation.  If you're not actually talking about the tag, then no, you shouldn't generally be formatting it as a tag.

Comment: ... even if you are talking about the tag, you should probably only once use proper tag-notation, and only hint at it for any additional occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that good practice? Or plain annoying?

The latter. There's already plenty of people using `inline code` to highlight random terms, and I sure wouldn't like to read posts [full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/full) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/of) [random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/random) [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tags).

The relevant tags are already below the question, so why would one repeat that *in* their question?